# Miniconda install gone wrong: edit path or uninstall and reinstall

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I work on a mac.

When installing miniconda I installed it to `/Applications/` rather that `~/Users/myusername/`.

The path for miniconda in my bash profile is

```
# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Applications/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.bash' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Applications/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Applications/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Applications/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

When I try and call packages I have installed in miniconda, such as `biopython` (Path = `/Applications/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/biopython-1.74.dist-info`), the packages are not recognised `ImportError: No module named bio`.

Can I modify my path so that the installed packages are recognised? Or should I start again by uninstalling anaconda and reinstalling.

Comment: What is the output, in Python, of `import sys; print(sys.executable)`?

Comment: @darthbith `/usr/bin/python`

Comment: Based on that, you're not actually running Conda's Python interpreter, but just the system one. How are you launching Python? Could you edit the question to show us your full `PATH`?

Comment: @merv apologies for my lack of knowledge, but how can I access this information?

Comment: How did you run `import sys; print(sys.executable)`? That is, how did you start a Python session in the first place? From the terminal, you can get the `PATH` and a bunch of other useful debugging stuff by typing `conda info --all`. Or you can just get `PATH` by typing `echo "$PATH"`.

Comment: @merv thank you. here is my result from `echo "$PATH"` : `/Applications/miniconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:6k/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Comment: What Mac version?

Comment: @merv macOS is mojave